# Flask Debug Mode

Tags: python, flask

How do I set the Debug mode in Flask to on? I am using a Windows system and the power shell terminal.

I tried using the command set FLASK_DEBUG=1 but it is not working. This is what my code looks like

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>"
```

I ran the code in Powershell using flask run but the debug mode displays a value of 0.

Comment: [This](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#debug-mode) excerpt from the documentation may help you.

Comment: You didn't say how you run it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I ran the code using flask run

Comment: Not in the comments, but in your question, which should be self-contained without forcing folk to trundle through the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

with two ways you can do it.

First way

1. create main.py and add your file content to it
2. in terminal set the flask environemnt using following command

   a. `set FLASK_APP=main.py`
   b. `set FLASK_DEBUG=True`
3. run the app using command `flask run`

second way

modify `main.py` and add following code at last

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

and use command `python3 main.py` to run the project

with these you can run proect in debug mode

Comment: Yeah the first option was what I used tho using a different approach to set the FLASK_DEBUG variables.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I have found the solution. I watched a youtube video and they said to run the following command $env:FLASK_DEBUG = "1". After running this command and running flask run again, this time Debug mode was on. Hope this helps :)

Comment: You still don't say how you run it, so it doesn't help much to know what you do beforehand. Please click [edit] and try to make your answer more user-friendly for others. Thank you.